# How can I import NetBeans project to Eclipse and vise versa?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-plugin

1. I would like to know what's the best easiest and best way to convert Netbeans projects to eclipse and vise versa.
2. If I will develop a swing app in Netbeans Will I be able to convert it completely without problem to eclipse?
3. Do you know where can I get some plugin for eclipse so it will have the same nice functionality as the visual designer we have in Netbeans?

Thanks

Comment: Should this be 3 separate questions?

Comment: @gobernador: Possibly, if they can stand on their own. We can't split questions though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a dist folder inside NetBeans workspace, containing a .war file. Import this war file into Eclipse. For this;
Open eclips IDE > Go to File Menu => Import => War
Above step will make package structure in Eclipse workspace similar to NetBeans. It’ll also prepare configuration file. Now you need to place source files only. For this
Go to src folder inside NetBeans folder => Copy all contents => Place them to src folder inside Eclipse folder.
Right click on Project name in right side panel of Eclipse IDE => Refresh

Comment: I think thats only applicable if you are importing Web Based app from Netbeans to Eclipse like any JSP project , because in my case I am working on a simple SWING , and there is no .war file.

Answer (score 2):

If you use maven, you can generate eclipse project files using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. NetBeans can import maven projects directly.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your third question, Google bought Instantiations some time back and has made the WindowBuilder Pro tool freely available. As I understand it, that's as good as, if not better, than Matisse in Netbeans.

https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/

Answer (score 1):

Answer to 3:
IMHO there is no Eclipse plugin that provides you with an UI builder as good as the one integrated in NetBeans. However, there are several UI builders for Eclipse. I personally use Eclipse Visual Editor (http://www.eclipse.org/vep/) since i don't like woriking with two different IDEs.

edit: I just tried to import a dummy NetBeans project with 3 classes in three different packages into Eclipse. I was able to do so but I had to manually enter the build path settings. So I assume it is possible but not without manual actions. I don't work with NetBeans on a regular basis so there might be other possibilities then New > Java Project and then selecting the location of the NetBeans project.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't care much for imports from other IDE's but it can create a "launch ant"-project.

Netbeans can read in Eclipse projects.  I am not familiar enough with it to say if it writes any changes back in a form Eclipse can understand.

Comment: Today I would create my application as a maven project.  Netbeans, Eclipse and IntelliJ all have good Maven support so it is very easy to do what you want.